# Estimating frequencies of a population

Tags: probability, estimation, population

I have a sample of size 1121 from a population of size 2171 and I don't have access to any additional samples. The counts are

```
   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14 
 737 158  70  44  24  15  20  12   6   9   3  10  10   3
```

I am trying to estimate the frequencies for the  population,

All points in the population are positive.  Would the naïve estimate of

$(737/1121)*2171$ points have value 1,

$(158/1121)*2171$ points have value 2, ect...

be the appropriate measure.

The sample is count data in a capture-reacpture analysis, i.e., among all capture periods there were a total of 1121 individuals captured. Among the captures, 748 individuals were captured once, 158 twice, ...these captures were actually buyers of a product. This was only small a portion of the total buyers. The total buyers are the population that is being estimated. It is assumed that the buyers that were not observed exhibit the same behavior as the buyers that were captured. I want to get a good estimate on the "buying" counts on the estimated population for each individual.

Would fitting a distribution be the right approach? If the distribution is the appropriate way, would I generate 2171 random values and use those counts to get my estimate.

Comment: How these values (1 to 14) are obtained ? Is there any chance to model or at least understand the process behind it ?

Comment: The sample data are actually frequency totals  from a capture-recapure analysis, and the population size is the estimate from the capture recapture analysis. So technically it is not a "sample" from the population. i tried to simplify the question. There may be some circular reasoning.

Comment: Another question which would help others. I assumed in the updated part of my answer that you wanted to predict outcome on a future sample. Is it the real setting that the remaining subjects took part in your experiment with the same conditions and it just happens that you don't have the related data. If not, mention it please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without more details, I find it risky to fit a distribution. At least for the first categories, you can have fairly good estimates for your population. 
The value you gave is correct, but let's have a look on the 95% confidence interval for the first categories. 
$$\hat{p}\pm z_{\alpha/2}\sqrt{\dfrac{\hat{p}(1-\hat{p})}{n} \cdot \frac{N-n}{N-1}}$$

You have $z_{\alpha/2}=1.96$, $N=2171$, $n=1121$  . According to my calculations it would give this simplified formula : $$\hat{p}\pm 0.04071\times\sqrt{\hat{p}(1-\hat{p})}$$
The highest width of this interval is given by $\hat{p}=1/2$ so you will end up with a 95% confidence interval more narrow than 0.02.

After your comment "So technically it is not a "sample" from the population" I am not really sure whether it's a legit estimation. Maybe you should go into more details how this sample is produced and why you want this estimation.

---

**Edit after OP details**

As I really don't know how to treat capture-recapture analysis, maybe there are some related distributions that indeed fit. I would suggest to edit your question adding these new informations. But, at first glance I don't see a problem with my answer. However as the counts should theoretically go down, maybe only fitting 6th to 14th with a distribution even a very simple one (like linear) could grant better estimations than what I suggested. But ...at second glance...this comment also suggest that the data can be really noisy, and that you want to predict future outcomes by this recapturing process. This is really not the same thing as sampling measures from a population.

So, finally, if what I think about your data and your goal is right, my answer can't really hold and I would suggest to go to fit your data with a distribution.

Comment: I edit my answer on the basis of your comment. Does it stop at 15 because there was no 15th capture in the experiment or because no buyers were captured ?

Comment: 14 is the maximum number of purchases that could occur, so the study was designed to only allow for 14 captures. So, yes there is no 15 count, the max is 14.

Comment: Why do you find it risky to fit a distribution? There are several candidate distributions for this kind of data, which is count data with a lot of dispersion. OP, I would start with fitting a negative binomial distribution to the data (including the count of cases with zero recaptures!). Then compare the observed to the expected number of cases. You may have a bit longer of a tail than the negative binomial. In this case, try a binomial mixture, or maybe there is some covariate in your data that separates your subjects into different groups w.r.t. risk of recapture.

Comment: I agree. My answer was based with no information given by the OP concerning the source of the data and with a biased idea of its objective With this total state of uncertainty, I think the best is to not fit and work on proportion estimation only (as half of the population was studied). When he gave me these informations in the comment of this answer, I changed my mind and asked him to add these crucial informations in his question, and I add a part in my answer. The related comments have been deleted.

Comment: But, if it's really the data of half of the sample of the studied population and the other data points were kind of lost or not recorded. I think the estimates given by simple proportion are fairly good, at least for the first points. Fitting a distribution can be a loss at least for the first categories. Maybe a bayesian analysis would allow to combine these two sources of informations.

Comment: Brash, by the capture recapture estimate there are 1050 unobserved buyers. It seems circular to me to use these as zero counts along with the sample counts because the sample counts were used to estimate those unobserved users. Is this common practice in capture-recapture analysis.

Comment: brumar, great analysis on the distribution of counts. I am studying buying habits at many locations and this type of random behavior in the high counts is quite prevalent. I am going to mark the question as solved because your insights were very helpful.